# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0 attempting to populate JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm subclassing JTable and using a DefaultTableModel to model my table data.  The following class sets up the JTable, and adds one row to the model.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JTable;  
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class SelectedFileTable extends JTable {
Vector<File> SelectedFiles = new Vector<File>(); 
DefaultTableModel Model    = new DefaultTableModel();

TableColumn ColumnName     = new TableColumn();
TableColumn ColumnSize     = new TableColumn();
TableColumn ColumnRmIcon   = new TableColumn(); 

ImageFilenameFilter Filter = new ImageFilenameFilter();

public SelectedFileTable() {
    super();
    this.setModel(Model);

    ColumnName.setHeaderValue(new String("Name") );
      ColumnName.setMinWidth(200);
    ColumnSize.setHeaderValue(new String("Size") );
      ColumnSize.setMinWidth(50); 
      ColumnSize.setMaxWidth(100);
    ColumnRmIcon.setHeaderValue(new String("Remove?") );
      ColumnRmIcon.setMaxWidth(100);
      ColumnRmIcon.setResizable(false);

    this.addColumn(ColumnName);
    this.addColumn(ColumnSize);
    this.addColumn(ColumnRmIcon);

    this.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    this.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
this.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(true);

this.addFile( new File("C:/temp/cfk.jpg") );
}
public void addFile(File file) {
    System.out.println("FileTable adding: " + file.getName() );
    if ( file.isDirectory() ) { 
        for ( File f : file.listFiles(Filter) ) {
            this.addFile(f);
        }
    } else { 
        if ( Filter.accept(file) ) {
            System.out.println("Accepting file; " + file.getName() );
            SelectedFiles.add(file);
            {
                String name = file.getName();
                Long size = new Long( file.length() );
                String tempstr = new String("X");

                System.out.println("RowItems before: " + Integer.toString(Model.getRowCount()) );
                Model.addRow( new Object[] { name, size, tempstr } );
                Model.fireTableDataChanged(); 
                System.out.println("RowItems start : " + Integer.toString(Model.getRowCount()) );
            }
            System.out.println("Done Accepting file; " + file.getName() );
        }
    }
}
public Iterator<File> iterator() { 
    return SelectedFiles.iterator();
}

}
```

At display/visualization time, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:432)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:622)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:1903)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:3911)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2072)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:1974)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1897)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:142)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:743)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1006)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:843)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:843)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:843)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:843)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:843)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:843)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:559)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:843)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintWithOffscreenBuffer(JComponent.java:4979)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintDoubleBuffered(JComponent.java:4925)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:996)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:21)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1709)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:248)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:224)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:254)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4060)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1791)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

I'm ripping my hair out - I haven't been able to find the root cause of this immensely simple use case.

Comment: I had never seen this out-of-bounds exception message until today. Thanks for helping me debug my application!

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: All of them.   What exactly is your specific issue?

Comment: @ChrisKaminski I guess that e. g. instance variables are supposed to start with a lowercase letter in Java

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you need to add columns to your TableModel. Your code adds UI columns to the table but doesn't add them to the model

Comment: @Chris: More specifically, you should add columns to the TableModel **instead** of explicitly adding them to the JTable.  It's also worth pointing out that you will get better performance from a List instead of a Vector, since you're not using the synchronization (and shouldn't have to pay for the overhead) that comes with a Vector.

Answer (score 19):

I ran on this issue too (with a JList and a DefaultListModel).
Dmitry's answer is right.

However, there is another thing: 
this exception can also be thrown if you don't modify the model in Swing's Event Dispatch Thread.

Doing the following can help you avoid this exception:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){
    //Update the model here
}});
```

http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-gui/3012/JList-JScrollPane-DefaultListModel-Updating

Comment: +1 Although the accepted answer is correct in this case, this is very important and was causing an issue for me

Answer (score 5):

Dmitry is right. Replace

```
this.addColumn(ColumnName);
this.addColumn(ColumnSize);
this.addColumn(ColumnRmIcon);
```

with

```
Model.addColumn(ColumnName);
Model.addColumn(ColumnSize);
Model.addColumn(ColumnRmIcon);
```

and now the Model knows about the columsn and won't throw an Exception anymore when you try to add a row to a model which thinks it has 0 columns

Answer (score 1):

From the JTable.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel() API:

"This method calls createDefaultColumnsFromModel if autoCreateColumnsFromModel changes from false to true. "

Vector throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range ( index < 0 || index >= size())

I guess the table model is missing the columns, as suggested by Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

**Replace your code with the following**
Here you need to remove first row only that should be iterated for all the rows

```
private void refreshTable() {

   int rowCount= model.getRowCount();

  // System.out.println(rowCount);

   for(int i=0;i<rowCount;i++ ){
        model.removeRow(0);
        //System.out.println(i);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another issue **might** be related when you use `RowSorter`. When you edit the model `RowSorter` *tries* to re-sort the old model. It should be automatically re-created and re-run on each changes of table model.

You can fix it by

```
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
jTableSentence.setModel(tableModel);
jTableSentence.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(tableModel));
jTableSentence.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

-Hayri

Comment: doesn't make sense to  set the autoCreate property _after_ setting the model and manually installing a new rowSorter. Instead, set the property to true _before_ setting the tableModel and be done.

Comment: No. From API we know that `This method calls createDefaultColumnsFromModel if autoCreateColumnsFromModel changes from false to true`. So it can be added afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
tabWindow.addTab(...);
```

with

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        tabWindow.addTab(...);
    }
});
```

Such situation can hapen when you change tabbed pane in action listener.

Comment: while might be true in some contexts ... it's completely unrelated to the question

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem because i was adding columns and rows to the JTable not to the model.

best way is this.

```
Object[][]rows = new Object[ ][ ] { {"a","b"} , {"c","d"} };
Object[]columns = new Object[] {"column1","column2"};
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(rows,columns));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry is right, but you simply have to update your model.
To do this, add the following to your code:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
for (int c = 0; c < table.getColumnCount(); c++) {
dtm.addColumn(table.getColumnName(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add `isCellEditable` method to your table model class with return false.

```
@Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
  {
    return false;
  }
```