# Unable to programatically scroll to last item in JList

Tags: java, swing

I have a JList nested inside of a JScrollPane.  When I add items to the JList, I want the JScrollPane to automatically scroll to the bottom of the JList so the last item is visible.  To do this, I have the following code:

```
getWordListScroller().getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().setValue(getWordListScroller().getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().getMaximum());
```

When I try using this code, however, the JScrollPane only scrolls to the second to last item, leaving the last item out of view.  This is not in any way desirable.  I've tried adding values to getMaximum(), but the issue persists.

How can I get the JScrollPane to scroll to the very bottom?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the [JList#ensureIndexIsVisible()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#ensureIndexIsVisible%28int%29) method:

```
JList wordList = getWordListScroller ();
int lastIndex = wordList.getModel().getSize() - 1;
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
   wordList.ensureIndexIsVisible(lastIndex);
}
```

Comment: Nice. Btw. thing to remember (because, forcing scroll is related to changing content) http://stackoverflow.com/a/7114267/210342

Comment: This worked great for me.  I was confused about the worldList = getWordListScroller().

But this works with a JList list = new Jlist();
list.ensureIndexIsVisible(lastIndex)

Answer (score 0):

While this answer didn't work for me, I found this:
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=623669 (post written by 'inopia')
Which works perfectly.

As he says:
"The problem here is that it can become a bit difficult to find an event that fires after both the ListModel, JList and JScrollPane have been updated."

Comment: Link to the forum post is unavailable and now get redirected to the oracle community main page.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet worked for me

```
private JList<String> lstDebug;

private void scrollToBottom(){
    int lastIndex = lstDebug.getModel().getSize()-1;
    if(lastIndex >= 0){
        lstDebug.ensureIndexIsVisible(lastIndex);
    }
}
```